# Generating the intersected timelines for ab tests

Tags: sql

I have AB test table it has columns like user_id, ab_test_name, ab_test_activation_time. Here is the example table for that.

| user_id | ab_test | ab_test_activation_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user_1 | AB_X | 2023-06-23 15:38:09 |
| user_1 | AB_Y | 2023-06-23 15:55:33 |
| user_1 | AB_Z | 2023-06-24 03:04:54 |

And I want to create timeline ranges for the combination of these AB tests. Here is the example result set I want to create.

| user_id | ab_test_1 | ab_test_2 | ab_test_3 | ab_start | ab_end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| user_1 | AB_X | null | null | 2023-06-23 15:38:09 | 2023-06-23 15:55:33 |
| user_1 | AB_X | AB_Y | null | 2023-06-23 15:55:33 | 2023-06-24 03:04:54 |
| user_1 | AB_X | AB_Y | AB_Z | 2023-06-24 03:04:54 | null |

Thanks for Any help or suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing using the below logic:

```
SELECT t1.user_id, t1.ab_test AS ab_test_1, t2.ab_test AS ab_test_2, t3.ab_test AS ab_test_3, 
       t1.ab_test_activation_time AS ab_start, t2.ab_test_activation_time AS ab_end
FROM your_table_name t1
LEFT JOIN your_table_name t2 ON t2.user_id = t1.user_id AND t2.ab_test_activation_time > t1.ab_test_activation_time
LEFT JOIN your_table_name t3 ON t3.user_id = t2.user_id AND t3.ab_test_activation_time > t2.ab_test_activation_time
WHERE t1.ab_test IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This query generates the date range between the start dates of AB_X and AB_Y for the combination of AB_X, AB_Y, and AB_Z. However, I believe that the result set can be further optimized for the final outcome. Perhaps by joining this result set with itself on the columns ab_test_2 and ab_test_1, it can produce the correct result. I'm not entirely sure how to do it, but I'll give it a try. Thanks for the suggestion.